# Issue with Hive Rank queries

Tags: sql, hive, where-clause, hiveql, rank

```
select season,violation_code, cnt, 
       RANK() over (Partition BY season order by cnt desc) AS rank 
  from
    (  select season,violation_code, 
              count(*) as cnt 
         from  ParkingViolations_seondary 
     group by season,violation_code
    ) tmp
where rank <= 3
```

I'm new to Hive. Can somebody help me what is wrong with the above query?
It throws the following error:

Error while compiling statement:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: line 4:6 Invalid table alias
>   or column reference 'rank': (possible column names are: season,
>   violation_code, cnt)

Any quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery to be able to address `rank` in the `where` clause:

```
select season, violation_code, cnt, rnk
from
( select season,violation_code, cnt, 
         RANK() over (Partition BY season order by cnt desc) AS rnk
    from
        (  select season,violation_code, 
                count(*) as cnt 
             from  ParkingViolations_seondary 
         group by season,violation_code
        ) tmp
)s
where rnk <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i was also able to get it working with the following:

SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT season,violation_code, cnt, RANK() over (Partition BY season ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS frequency
    FROM
        (SELECT season,violation_code, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM  ParkingViolations_seondary 
        WHERE (violation_code <> 0) and (street_code1 <> 0 or street_code2 <> 0 or street_code3 <> 0)
        GROUP BY season,violation_code)TMP
)TMP1
WHERE frequency <= 3;